# setTimeout to throttle http request

Tags: javascript, ajax, http

I've a set of big array, and getUser is a method that call an api. How do I call the api every 5 seconds? because now the api doesn't allow x number of request per second.

myarr has about 100 items.

```
myarr.forEach(id => {
   getUser(id).then(resp => {})
})
```

Comment: Please provide the complete code

Comment: make a queue...

Comment: @epascarello need to install a queue lib?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a loop and `setTimeout`, incrementing the timeout duration based on the current index.

```
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]

arr.forEach((num, index) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    mockApiCall(num).then(console.log)
  }, index * 5000) // Increase timeout duration by 5 seconds for each element
})

// Emulate the HTTP call, replace this with your API call
function mockApiCall(number) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    resolve(`Sample result from api/${number}`)
  })
}
```

Note, this is very basic and doesn't take into account error handling, retries, backoff etc.

Comment: why do we need to have another function? can it be like this?

`myarr.forEach((id, index) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
           getUser(id).then(resp => {})
    }, index * 5000)
})`

Answer (score 1):

Just use `setInterval` and clear it when it is done.

```js
let i = 0;

const timeId = setInterval(() => {
  getUser(myArr[i++]).then(...);
  i >= myArr.length && clearTimeout(timeId);
}, 5000);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a queue where you pop it off an array.

**5 seconds after the call is done**

```
var items = [1,2,3,4,5,6];

function fetchNext () {
  var currentData = items.shift();
  getUser(currentData)
    .then(resp => {
      if (items.length) {
        window.setTimeout(fetchNext, 5000);
      }
    })
}
```

**5 seconds between calls**

```
var items = [1,2,3,4,5,6];

function fetchNext () {
  var currentData = items.shift();
  getUser(currentData)
    .then(resp => {
    })
  if (items.length) {
    window.setTimeout(fetchNext, 5000);
  }
}
```

Example hitting an api:

```js
function getUser(x) {
  return fetch('https://randomuser.me/api/?results=x')
    .then((response) => response.json())
}


var items = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];

function fetchNext() {
  var currentData = items.shift();
  getUser(currentData)
    .then(resp => {
      console.log(resp.results[0].name.first)
    })
  if (items.length) {
    window.setTimeout(fetchNext, 5000);
  }
}

fetchNext()
```

Comment: Nice answer but it doesn't ensure the statement "every 5 seconds".

Comment: It is every 5 seconds AFTER the call is made and received.

Comment: What if `getUser(something)` takes 10 seconds?

Comment: So if OP wants it every 5, move it outside the then... Not a big deal...

Comment: this won't work, I have no exact predirection over who long the API will that, sometime it's fast, sometime it's slow, so must put the timeout in the promise

Comment: Not sure how it will not work. You were given 2 options, one where it is every 5 seconds and another that is every 5 seconds after a call is received.

Comment: I think OP's concern is the api rate limit, he mention the API allow only certain number of request per second, I think the good solution should not be using setTimeout with a fixed seconds, use queue easily solve this problem.

Comment: @akibo This is what OP asked for..... unclear why people say it is wrong. It is a queue with two different options for a delay. lol

Comment: OP propose a solution which isn't the best, your answer is correct to his not-so-efficient solution. lol. how do you know the promise can be resolve in 5 seconds? it's a waste of time to set a 5 seconds timeout too, we can't assume the promise will return in the same amount of time. so we should use queue isn't it?

Comment: Dude..... or Dudette.... OP wanted a 5 second delay between calls..... This gives the 5 second delay. lol The 5 seconds is to throttle the calls to avoid going over the limit. It is a common thing to do.

Comment: hmm I think what he said is right, what if in between the api response isn't coming back after 5 seconds?

Comment: @Emily The one example waits for the response..... The other one does not. The example that hits `randomuser` does not wait for the response. This pattern is a lot better than generating tons of timeout calls with longer and longer delays. In reality this is bare bones Normally it would have code inside to determine if it was throttled and to retry failed calls.